# Interpreting loss and metric curve

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, training-data

I am trying to train Unet model with the following parameters:

```
droput_: 0.2,
activation_: sigmoid,
activation_inner_: relu,
learning_rate_: 0.0001,
epsilon_: 1e-07,
loss : mse,
metric : rmse,
kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=0.01, l2=0.01), bias_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=0.01, l2=0.01)
```

I ran the model and got the following plot for loss and metric.

[image: Loss Graph]

[image: Metric graphs (rmse)]

Blue = Training,
Orange = Validation

Please help in interpreting the loss (mse) and metric(rmse) graph.

- Is it overfitting?
- Does the metric plot is ok?

Answer (score 0):

DATA is unique enough they change a bit when loss decreases with a slicely effects on mean square errors or longer time it keep doing same behaviour that is samples.

**[ Sample ]:**

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf
import h5py

from tensorflow_examples.models.pix2pix import pix2pix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
OUTPUT_CLASSES = 3

database_buffer = "F:\\models\\buffer\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\TF_DataSets_01.h5"
database_buffer_dir = os.path.dirname(database_buffer)

checkpoint_path = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\TF_DataSets_01.h5"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)
loggings = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\loggings.log"

if not exists(checkpoint_dir) : 
    os.mkdir(checkpoint_dir)
    print("Create directory: " + checkpoint_dir)
    
if not exists(database_buffer_dir) : 
    os.mkdir(database_buffer_dir)
    print("Create directory: " + database_buffer_dir)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Functions
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
def unet_model(output_channels:int):
    inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[32, 32, 3])
    # inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[128, 128, 3])

    # Downsampling through the model
    skips = down_stack(inputs)
    x = skips[-1]
    skips = reversed(skips[:-1])

    # Upsampling and establishing the skip connections
    for up, skip in zip(up_stack, skips):
        x = up(x)
        concat = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()
        x = concat([x, skip])

    # This is the last layer of the model
    last = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
    filters=output_channels, kernel_size=3, strides=2,
    padding='same')  #64x64 -> 128x128

    x = last(x)

    return tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x, name="U-net")

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
DataSet
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

train_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    validation_split=0.2)
    
train_generator.fit(x_train)


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
# base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=[128, 128, 3], include_top=False)
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=[32, 32, 3], include_top=False)

# Use the activations of these layers
layer_names = [
    'block_1_expand_relu',   # 64x64
    'block_3_expand_relu',   # 32x32
    'block_6_expand_relu',   # 16x16
    'block_13_expand_relu',  # 8x8
    'block_16_project',      # 4x4
]
base_model_outputs = [base_model.get_layer(name).output for name in layer_names]

# Create the feature extraction model
down_stack = tf.keras.Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=base_model_outputs)
down_stack.trainable = False

up_stack = [
    pix2pix.upsample(512, 3),  # 4x4 -> 8x8
    pix2pix.upsample(256, 3),  # 8x8 -> 16x16
    pix2pix.upsample(128, 3),  # 16x16 -> 32x32
    pix2pix.upsample(64, 3),   # 32x32 -> 64x64
]

unet_model = unet_model( output_channels=OUTPUT_CLASSES )
unet_model.summary()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam( learning_rate=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07, name='Nadam' )

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError( reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO, name='mean_squared_error' )

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
# model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'])
unet_model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=[ tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError( name='root_mean_squared_error' ) ])
# metric : rmse,


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: FileWriter
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
if exists(checkpoint_path) :
    unet_model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)
    print("model load: " + checkpoint_path)
    input("Press Any Key!")

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = unet_model.fit( train_generator.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=1, subset='training'), epochs=5, steps_per_epoch=1 )
unet_model.save_weights(checkpoint_path)

# print( history.history )
# {'loss': [25.04973030090332], 'root_mean_squared_error': [5.004970550537109]}

plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['root_mean_squared_error'])
plt.legend(['loss', 'root_mean_squared_error'])
plt.autumn()
plt.show()
plt.close()

input('...')
```

Comment: Thank you @jirayu for your answer. But what exactly are you trying to show in the sample code? 
And in my loss curve, it is learning perfectly but in the metric curve, there is lof of fluctuation. Whats the reason for that?